# Renyoukei at the end of a sentence

Tags: renyōkei

https://www.spookizthemovie.jp/

I'm curious about the renyoukei at the end of the last sentence of the description:

> ある日、偶然拾ったスマホがきっかけで、キュラが、好奇心旺盛な人間の少女・ハナに出会ってしまい・・・。

What does it do at the end of a sentence? Google Translate makes 好奇心旺盛な人間の少女・ハナに出会ってしまい a consequence of 偶然拾ったスマホがきっかけで and I would think 出会ってしまい has a conjoining function, but I can't anything confirming that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what you are asking, but 出会ってしまい… means the story goes on, but the sentence omits the rest part after the two characters meet. In this case the conjunction form is used since the following part is just omitted.

Comment: 1.) Huh, okay. I ought to have asked before spending so much time trying to figure this out on my own. 2.) Okay, that's actually all I need to know. I'm still no good at spotting  omitted sentences, even when "…"  is used, so thanks!

Comment: @Andrea Great, don't forget to accept the answer (The green check under vote) :)